# How to create a half scene?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am working on a project where I need to create a scene and export it only for the right or the left eye and export just a black scene for the other eye using Aframe. Is there an easy way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Please share us the specific part of your code to show what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [aframe stereo component](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component).

then you can use the attribute **stereo** to define what should be displayed for what eye:

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: #C03546" stereo="eye:left"></a-entity>
<a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: #3546C0" position="0 5 0" stereo="eye: right"></a-entity>
```

example from the same link.